# Flutter: How to update FloatingActionButton color on condition?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I want to **update the color** of the `FloatingActionButton` on certain conditions(after the user update his values) I manage to set the color but only if the user click on the button where should I put the `setstate` or how can I achieve that?

```
FloatingActionButton.extended(
      onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
          if(departureCity!=null && arrivalCity!=null && bol){
            bol2=true;
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              //MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SeatScreen()),
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BusSearchResults(departureCity,arrivalCity,_date)),
            );
          }
        });

      },
      label: const Text('Search'),
      backgroundColor: bol2? Color(0xff5348bf):Color(0xffd3d3d3) ,
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 bol2 = !bol2;
```

just write this instead of (bol2 = true ;) in your setState();

Comment: But I want to update the color when the condition is true, which means ** before the user click on the button**.
it's like a disabled button, only enable when the condition is true

Comment: can you send the code with the condition you want to implement.

Comment: It's too long code I think, so let me recap, first I created null variables, then if the user select items in a DropdownMenu, these variable get the selected data and when those variables are no longer null the condition is true which I test it using this  `if(departureCity!=null && arrivalCity!=null && bol)`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value of bol2 to the opposite every time on click like given below. And try not to wrap everything in setState() since it's unnecessary.

```
FloatingActionButton.extended(
  onPressed: (){
    setState(() {
      if(bol2){
        bol2=false;
      }
      else{
        bol2=true;
      }
    });
    if(departureCity!=null && arrivalCity!=null){
      bol2=true;
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>BusSearchResults(departureCity,arrivalCity,_date)),
      );
    }
  },
  label: const Text('Search'),
  backgroundColor: bol2? Color(0xff5348bf):Color(0xffd3d3d3),
),
```

Comment: I want to make a color for the elevation button when the condition is false once the user choose some data (this mean the condition is set to true) then the button change it's color, I mean before clicking on it.